# SQL Server explorer pane in Spyder IDE

Tags: database, ide, spyder

I have seen many IDEs support connecting to a database and provide a view or pane of the database with expandable items for tables and the columns in those tables.  This would be great to see in Spyder, but all my searching hasn't revealed anything for Spyder. I have thought about building my own plug-in, but if there's a known solution out there, I'd love to see it.

I have looked through various google search results around Spyder plugins and Spyder database interactions, but have found nothing regarding viewing a database schema inside of Spyder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer*) *Short answer*: There's no such explorer and we don't have plans to build one.

*Long answer*: This would be not so hard by relying in an abstraction database package called [Blaze](https://github.com/blaze/blaze/). Unfortunately, that project seems unmaintained now.